# Raising bot events from client

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

In a typical bot service, we have event handler like OnInvoke, OnMessageReceived etc but how does the client decide what type of event to raise (InvokeEvent, MessageReceivedEvent etc)?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the channel, but for the most part the connector (Directline for Webchat, Teams connector for Teams client), is the one doing that. Invoke is a Teams thing as you might know. It really depends on the channel and the actual type of event (for example, at least in Directline, conversationUpdate is started/triggered by the connector to connect both the bot and client).